# How to write \1 in string

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I'm trying to write `\1` in a string, but I can't do it. I would appreciate if somebody helped me with this strange behaviour. [Here](https://repl.it/BzDt/2) is an example with some explaining.

EDIT: Adding example output

`puts "\1 <- null"`

`puts "\\1 <- slash one"`

works!

but typing 
`"\1"`
`"\\1"`

in the irb command line yields

`"\1"`

`=> "\u0001`

`"\\1"`

`=> "\\1"`

Comment: Please edit your question to include your example code and explanation. Links to other sites tend to go bad, making this question and any answers less useful to future visitors.

Comment: Do you want literally *backslash one*?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We expect you to include your code and evidence of effort in the question itself, not in a link to somewhere else. Links rot then break, leaving your question making no sense to anyone.

Comment: @Jordan Example code added. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @sawa neither `\1` nor `\\1` can result in a string of "\1"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to get it:

```
"\\1"
'\1'
?\\ + ?1
```

Remember that the way it will show up is always `"\\1"`, which means *literal backslash, one*, which is what you want. The way to know that this is correct is to use `puts`:

```
puts "\\1"
# => \1
```

Inside of double-quoted strings, backslashes have significant meaning. `\n` means the newline character. In single quoted strings, that's two characters: backslash and `n`.

You can even test this:

```
"\\1".chars
# => ["\\", "1"]

'\1'.chars
# => ["\\", "1"]
```

So you can see Ruby is interpreting that as two characters, not three. Don't be fooled by the second backslash inside a double-quoted string. That's how a literal backslash is represented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @mhz Let me know if that works, and if it does, accept it as your solution. Makes it easy for other people to find that way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `puts '\1'`? (single quotes instead of double)
I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but if that helps, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your command line shows "\1" because irb does .inspect on the object, which escapes the string. So essentially \1 is properly stored, but when it's displaying it, it adds another \ to indicate to you that it's escaped

Answer (score 0):

When I'm in IRB and type `\1`, the value returned is `\u0001` which is Ruby's way of
representing the character.

When I write `puts('\1`), the behavior is the same in IRB and when running 
a script. I see a unicode character map as follows

```
0 0
0 1
```

This won't be the same output on all platforms (it depends on how unicode is
displayed). So that's probably why you see no output on the repl.it example.